# How to randomize a specific property of a geometry node object instanced into another geometry node

Tags: geometry-nodes

I recently learned how to pass attributes such as location, from one node tree A to another node tree B where it is instanced.

However here, I need to play not with the location, rotation etc.. but with a specific property I set up in A so that I can randomize it in its instances in B.

In the attached picture I made the eye in one geometry node where I can open and close the eye lids (controlling a simple math node). I need those eyes to blink, but randomly in the node tree where they are instanced. How to reference and play around with that value?

[Here is the file cleaned up](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u0zsxz9hy2omd09/question2.blend?dl=0)
[image]

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you mean. I haven't looked at the file yet, but according to the description, this might be difficult, since after an instantiation you no longer have access to individual and previously available parameters. Please read this post for more information: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/274485/145249

Comment: Thank you for the article, which is exactly the same issue I have. Looks like I could get away with it duplicating my eyes 3 or 4 times and feeding the collection to my final node tree. Hopefully it will get easier with future updates.

Comment: Currently, I am not aware of any improvements in this regard. Above all: An instance remains an instance, so it will probably take a few more versions until something happens in this direction. Should I mark the question as duplicate, or do we wait? Maybe someone has an idea for a workaround if you don't get anywhere with your solution.

Comment: Looks like we hit a wall with this one. Can be tagged as duplicate I guess. Thanks so much.