# How to access an object's geometry nodes in geometry node setup of other object?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I created a mesh with one GeometryNode which I'd like to re-use and instantiate multiple times in a GeometryNode of another object.
To create some variation in the look of the re-usable mesh, I routed two parameters to the input of the GeometryNode where I want to plug in some random values per instance later:

[image]

From other pages, I figured that these input-attributed need to be added with the same name to the "Attributes" of the mesh carrying the GeometryNode modifier:

[image]

So far so good...

Now I want to access/set these attributes in the GeomeryNode of ANOTHER mesh. Accessing the geometry is no problem, I do this by the "Object Info" node with reference to the "reusable mesh" object. I thought accessing an attribute can be done via the "Transfer Attribute" node like this:

[image]

When I check the values via "Viewer" node and spreadsheet, all values are zero where I expect a non-zero number.

Questions:

- How can I create a re-usable object ("Mesh1") with GeometryNode (GN1) and access the input attributes of the node by some GeometryNode belonging to a different mesh?
- How can I set the input values of the GN1 in some other mesh with GN?
- Is this possible at all?

Any ideas appreciated

Comment: I see more of a structural problem here: you can't create instances this way with different parameters. More about this here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274485/how-can-i-instantiate-a-procedural-node-group-with-different-parameters

Comment: Ok, so I need to re-design this thing with the instances. However, do you have an idea how to realize what I want to do for only one instance? So to say only starting with "Object Info"?

Comment: Current status of the project is available here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Av5V9BFPZrWrgRX_Z-CHzjR59bhc?e=gu5626

Comment: The problematic node group controlling the window blinds is at mesh "Proxy_Windows_SB3_3rdFloor", lowest Node group called "NodeGroup"

Comment: In order to be able to use attributes in later node groups, you first store them in the geometry with 'Store Named Attribute`.