# How do I extract the width of Bounding Box node of a Collection with multiple objects?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, instances, loop

I’m trying to use a Bounding Box node and extracting its width to transfer it to the window. The problem is I can’t find a way to do this operation on a Collection.

#### I’m trying to create this setup:

1. Create multiple cubes
2. Instance a point on these cubes
3. In each instance, there will be a window that uses the cube width to control its width

[image]

#### I succeed when I tried to do this with single object.

[image]
[image]

#### The problem is when I try to expand this setup to a Collection. It did not work.

[image]

---

#### Where the problem might be.

It seems that the problem might be in this part. With a single object, the socket returns the values correctly, but in the collection it is just zero.

Does somebody known how to get the data from the Bounding Box?

[image]

### EDIT:

I found a workaround. It’s not as clean as I was intending, but it works.
As the Loop Node still doesn’t exit, I had to create a group for each instance and join them afterward.

[image]

This is the group setup.

[image]

I’ll probably revisit this node setup once a Loop Node is available.

### EDIT2 (SOLUTION):

I was able to achieve the solution with `Repeat Zone`, I’m using *Blender 4.0 Alpha*.

The node setup didn’t change that much, It’s just more automatic. I don’t have to manually set a node for each window/ door, the `Repeat Zone` does it for me.

#### Final Result

[image]

#### Node Setup

[image]

[image]

Comment: The bounding box is actually not the problem in this setup. The problem lies more in the structural setup: You can't instantiate objects with different parameters at multiple points this way with `Instance on Points` unfortunately. Please have a closer look at the following question/answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274485/how-can-i-instantiate-a-procedural-node-group-with-different-parameters

Comment: Please let me know if the linked question could (at least partially) explain your problem. Since the setup you show here is not solvable, I would close this question. Please try to ask the question again with a different focus, or edit it here so that it is possible to give a different answer. Thank you! PS: I don't want to say that there is no solution for this problem, but you would have to change some things structurally, which is why we wouldn't get any further without your blend file.

Comment: Thanks. I did read the post you linked and undestood the limitation of instancing in my setup. I will probably search for a diferent approach to this problem. BTW, just for curiosity's sake, this is the file I'm currently working on https://blend-exchange.com/b/OYeb58lN/