# How can I drive the value of a node in the geometry node tree of an instanced object?

Tags: geometry-nodes

.blend file:

[image]

I have a fairly simple Geometry nodes tree for adding wings to a butterfly mesh object.

[image]

The wings are added by instancing two different mesh objects on two points:

[image]

I can change the angle of the wings by changing a value input:

[image: SS2]

In a separate object, I am instancing copies of the butterfly object (with the wings Geometry nodes) on a point cloud:

[image: SS3]

[image]

I would like to know if there is any way that I can create a DIFFERENT Random Value for the Wing Angle in each instance of the butterfly object.

Something similar to the Random output of the **Object Info/Particle Info** nodes when working with material nodes, which produces a different random value between 0 and 1 for each object/particle.
I would like to generate a different random value for each **instance** of the butterfly (and use this random value to drive the 'Wing Angle').

Comment: ...maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274485/how-can-i-instantiate-a-procedural-node-group-with-different-parameters/274486#274486

Comment: really? you close a question with "maybe related"...? wow...

Comment: @Chris Yes, at first I thought it might be related, and when I looked into it more, I came to the conclusion that it is definitely the same question. Or was I mistaken? Do you disagree? ...I'm not entirely infallible either.

Comment: Thanks both. Having read the linked question I agree that it speaks to the same issue I am having. My situation is slightly different as my original 'instance' is not truly a procedurally-generated object, but the information has cleared things up for me enough that I should be able to figure things out from here. Cheers!

Comment: @SlickRed I'm glad the other answer was able to help you out! Sorry that I closed the question so quickly.

Comment: @quellenform: yes, i agree that it is the same question. I was just shocked about your formulation. You wrote "maybe" - with this i would expect that you don't close the question - only if you are sure. That's all.