# Geometry nodes: different instance parameters for each instance

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

Is there a way to control instances so each one of them has different parameters?

For example:

1. I have four instances of star and I want each one of them to have the amount of points

- based on the index of the point in the resampled curve.
- i know if we use the index values  the first would have 0 points , the second would be a point, and a second eventually would be a a line - that doesn't matter - i can remap values latter.

2. Also is there a way to generate in GN sequence of values (instead of random) like for example: 1,2,3..8 or 2,4,8,10 ???

Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Maybe helpful, maybe a duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274485/

Comment: Thank you! I was looking exactly for this kind of solution that generates objects first with certain parameters -  'geometry to instances' and repeat zone should solve the problem