# Geonodes unique instances

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have this geo nodes setup but I can't figure out how to have a different 'seed' and 'iterations' for each instance of the stack of books.

I can do it manually and change the seed and iteration on each duplicate, but I have 100s of these and manual will be my last resort

link go blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RPDYEXvdyRD7Q3V_C3f1xuML2NcWZlJu/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome! Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274485/

Comment: Thank you, my friend. It certainly works, and I might stick to this solution, but it's very evident that it repeats even though I have a dozen versions