How do I display the position of each point/vertex?

How do I display the position of each point/vertex? As you can see the position output is not working the way I want it to and every thing is just 0. Even if I move the whole thing around it stays as a bunch of 0s.

https://github.com/Griperis/GeometryNodesAttributeViewer This absolute god send made exactly what I was looking for.

Geonode : Display instances scales as text , Display vertex index with Geometry Nodes

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274485/how-can-i-instantiate-a-procedural-node-group-with-different-parameters/274486#274486
