Is it possible to make each instance surface randomly uneven/distorted using noise texture node in geometry nodes, without using Realize Instance?
I have 6 cuboid shaped instances. And now I want to make surface of each of them uneven/distorted using Noise Texutre node and Geometry Nodes only. And each of them must not have same distortion. It should be random for each.
One approach I found is this:

As you can see, each instance's surface is uneven/distorted and also that is random for each of them.
But it uses Realize Instance node after Instance on Points and I've read that it may affect performance because of Realize Instance, when I have complex geometry and a lot more instances.
So I'm wondering if it is possible to achieve same using Geometry Nodes only but without using Realize Instance after Instance on Points node?

Please read https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/274486/19307

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos thanks. I guess my question can be marked duplicated.
